# MySQL Server Configuration failing

Tags: mysql, configuration, 64-bit

I want to Setup a MySQL database and it is failing within the server configuration.
I am using Win7 x64 and MySQL Installer version 5.5.28.3.
I get the following output:

http://s10.postimage.org/bgc2jjhqx/mysql.png

Thx for your help ;)

Comment: Have you checked that you are running the installer with sufficient privileges to set up services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try WAMP Server http://www.wampserver.com/en/ fastest easiest way to setup a MySQL database I have ever found.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use USBWebserver. It comes with PhpMyAdmin that uses MySQL. Just search for it